# Applet does not display in browser

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I am using a JApplet which have swing components in it and the event handling is done by AWT listeners. My applet is fine when I run it in applet viewer but when I run it in my browser, it does not displays up only and empty space with message on top that:

```
Error, Click for details
```

Where could be the problem and how could I resolve it?

The stack trace is :

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AudioApplet.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the applet tag I used to embed my applet into HTML

```
   <applet code="AudioApplet.class" width="700" height="700">
    Java applet that draws animated bubbles.
    </applet>
```

Comment: mostlikely you have exception error in the applet

Comment: recheck your html syntax

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace

Comment: *"Where could be the problem.."* Well, it says `Error, Click for details` So ***click it*** for more ***details***.  Copy/paste those details here along with 1) The code 2) A link to the broken applet.  Failing more information, we do not have a snow-ball's chance in Hades of helping you.

Comment: I am running my .class file separately in my browser, so how can I get the stack trace ?

Comment: Even when running in the browser there is still a Java console. And I doubt the browser would say "Click for details" and then not show details when you click on it. And what do you mean by "running the .class file in the browser" ... a browser cannot open a .class file directly

Comment: *"I am running my .class file separately in my browser, so how can I get the stack trace ?"* Exactly the same way you would for a Jar.  That question reads like nonsense.  As an aside. 1) Add @PersonName to ensure the person to whom you are replying is 'notified' of the new comment.  2) **Post a link to the applet.**

Comment: @Muhammad Salman Farooq should be better to describe detailed question based on [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), otherwise this question isn't answerable, please then everything there will be shots to the dark

Comment: @AndrewThompson Java Plug-in 10.3.1.255
Using JRE version 1.6.0_35-b10 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Hamza
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>

Comment: Type `5` when the console has focus (to make the trace detailed), then go to the browser and refresh the page with `F-5`.  Copy/paste the information and as an **edit to the question**.

Comment: Note:  I've heard a couple of questions like this over the last few days and suspect there is a bug in a recent JRE.  That is why it would be most helpful if you could prepare a small example for others to test (a web page that tries to load the applet, a link here for us to go to it).  You might be surprised to discover the applet works for other people.

Comment: @AndrewThompson but he is not using latest JRE, his is Using JRE version 1.6.0_35-b10 ....

Comment: Yes exactly, I am not using the latest version of JRE.

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanFarooq please provide `stacktrace` not console help as you have commented above.

Comment: @Harmeet 1.6 is at `Java SE 6 Update 37`, only 2 micro-versions beyond that.  When I wrote 'recent' I did not mean 1.7, just 'recently released'.

Comment: @HarmeetSingh I am trying to do so, but when ever I click on "Click for details" message, my browser goes to not responding state.

Comment: The browser freezes?  What browser is it? Try it in two other browsers.  As an aside, I seem to need to repeat everything I write.  That becomes boring very quickly.  Please lift your game or I will abandon this thread.

Comment: @AndrewThompson ok I got it then its a recent release, *1.6.0_35-b10* - `b10` does that mean *beta* ??

Comment: @HarmeetSingh  I think so, but I'm no expert on version numbers.

Comment: [check that in linked database](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/news/432479/is-java-7-still-insecure-oracle-patch-doesnt-fix-underlying-vulnerability)

Comment: @AndrewThompson It is Mozilla Firefox 15.0.1. I tried the same on Internet Explorer and that freezes too.

Comment: ClassNotFoundException: did you forgot to put the fully qualified name of your class?

Comment: I have now put the fully qualified name of my class like "com/audio/AudioApplet.class", and now its loading in browser. Thanks to all of you for your responce

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanFarooq : Please do check the version on the classpath of your system, by writing **javac -version** and do check the **JRE version** used by your browser (which is what you had posted before in your comments). Now compare them both, do they both refer to the same version !!

Answer (score 0):

these are the things you can correct/check:

•Check the Java Console log for errors.
•Check the syntax of the applet's Java Network Launch Protocol (JNLP) file. Incorrect JNLP files are the most common reason for failures without obvious errors.
•Check the JavaScript syntax if deploying using the runApplet function of the Deployment Toolkit. See Deploying an Applet for details.
Problem: The Java Console log displays java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

•Make sure your Java source files compiled correctly.
•If deploying using the  tag, check that the path to the applet JAR file is specified accurately in the archive attribute.
•If launching using a JNLP file, check the path in the jar tag in the JNLP file.
•Make sure the applet's JAR file, JNLP file, and web page are located in the correct directory and reference each other accurately.
Problem: I was able to build the code once, but now the build fails even though there are no compilation errors.

•Close your browser and run the build again. The browser most likely has a lock on the JAR file, because of which the build process is unable to regenerate the JAR file.
Problem: When I try to load a web page that has an applet, my browser redirects me to www.java.com without any warning

•The applet on the web page is most likely deployed using the Deployment Toolkit script. The applet may require a later version of the Java Runtime Environment software than the version that currently exists on the client. Check the minimumVersion parameter of the runApplet function in the applet's web page. See Deploying an Applet for details.
Problem: I fixed some bugs and re-built my applet's source code. When I reload the applet's web page, my fixes are not showing up.

•You may be viewing a previously cached version of the applet. Close the browser. Open the Java Control Panel and delete temporary internet files. This will remove your applet from cache. Try viewing your applet again.